# Shared variables among subclasses

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, variables

I have a problem with inherited classes. Have a look at the following **VB.NET 2.0 / VS 2005** code:

```
MustInherit Class templateclass
    Public Shared x As String
End Class

Class child1
    Inherits templateclass
End Class

Class child2
    Inherits templateclass
End Class
```

The templateclass has a shared variable x which is of course inherited by the child classes. But I wonder that all child classes share only one x! **Until now I thought that shared variables are only shared among the instances of a class, not among all childs.** This is very annoying because I have a base class which I need in two slightly different versions and they should not "share the shared" variables. And because the classes have a lot of shared variables, shadowing each in the childs would be very... inelegant and cause a lot of work.
Has anyone a better solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Sagi

Comment: You can make your abstract class(MustInherit) generic, have a look at this C# question on the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542171/c-abstract-class-static-field-inheritance

Comment: You need to tell us what version of VB.net.

Comment: The problem solved itself by redesigning the whole thing. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the shared state in a dedicated class (as non-shared members), and give each of the child classes a shared member of that class. If you need to access shared state through an instance, you can implement a property that both child classes inherit, returning the shared state of the particular subclass. Note, however, that this property cannot be shared itself.